# How far back can I go with Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get my photos and status updates in my iphone app. But it seems that after about 10-15 API calls you can't go to the next page anymore. I noticed that Facebook does not give everything in one graph call, they'll give you this thig at the end of each API call:

```
"paging":{"previous":"https:\/\/graph.
facebook.com\/myid\/statuses?access_token=somebigvalue","next":"https:\/\/graph
.facebook.com\/myid\/statuses?access_token=anothersomebigvalue"}}
```

Now I wonder if there's any way I could go back and grab photos from very early days (i.e. status updates which I was tagged the first few days I joined to facebook). Has anyone got any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out that I can only go back one and a half year, until June 2009. I'm not happy with this, and I might open another question to see if I can go further back with other methods.

Comment: You can get posts all the way back to when the user joined facebook. See my answer on your other question about this: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/8979457/223594

Answer (score 0):

I tried facebook api with REST framework for Java and I was able to get my status messages for an year ago. So if you are pleased with an interval of one year - this is what you can get.

Comment: did facebook say anything about statuses older than one year? I've just tried it and I think it's even less than 1 year for me... This is weird, can't find documentation on facebook either...

Comment: Maybe the graph is limited for the String information and if you have longer messages it preserves less number. In my case it was an year, but I'm posting a status message in 4-5 days or even more rare.

Comment: Hang on, it might be more than a year, I found a bug in my program that doesn't actually go back more than a few months... Will report in a few days/hours depending on how it goes.