# Facebook Graph API does not give any data earlier than 2011?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm the author of [Fazzle app](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=fazzle%20app&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/fazzle/id448174316?mt=8&ei=suwTT6CgD4GbiQe62oDRBA&usg=AFQjCNHvIe4kWJR4bIxArwuM_P3KqZMHkg) on iPhone. What my app does is basically download user status updates and sort them in various orders (e.g. most liked, most commented).

I have been wondering if Facebook allow developers to get user's status updates since the day they joined Facebook, because when I launched the app I can only get user statuses from 2009. Today I just discovered that Facebook limits Graph API calls down to just since 2011.

I tried looking at documentations, [asked around here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4276780/361247), and contacted Facebook through their forum. However so far there is no word on this limitation in Graph API. Did I miss something? Is there any other way for me to get data for status updates earlier than 2011?

You can test it yourself [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). Use this GET request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/(your_user_id)/statuses?limit=99999
```

Scroll down and you'll find out that not everything's downloaded.

Is this because of conflict of interest with Facebook Timeline? If so, that sucks.

Logged as a bug [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/104392053016265). Still hoping someone can point out my mistakes if there's any.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely you can get older posts from Graph API; there is no limit (at least not that I am aware of). Use the `since` and `until` parameters to page back through results, instead of `offset`:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=[token]&until=1165474447
```

[Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for **Paging** doesn't go very in-depth on `since` and `until`:

> When querying connections, there are several useful parameters that enable you to filter and page through connection data:
>
> - limit, offset: https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?limit=3`
> - until, since (a unix timestamp or any date accepted by [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)):
>     https://graph.facebook.com/search?until=yesterday&q=orange

But basically, `until` is like saying "Give me posts up until this date", and since is similar, "Give me posts since this date". So you can scroll all the way back through a user's feed using a loop something like this:

```
// pseudocode
timestamp = now
do {
  posts = graph.get(/me/feed?until=timestamp)
  if posts.length == 0: break;
  // process posts
  timestamp = posts[0].created_time // first should be the oldest, in theory
} while (1)
```

Replace `until` with `since` and oldest `created_time` with the newest to go forwards in time, e.g. to grab any newer posts since the last time the user ran the app.

Comment: I've just tried this: (my_id)/statuses&since=01+January+2009 and 747882379/statuses&since=01-01-2009 but neither of them work. They gave me an empty data set.

Comment: Make sure the dates you give it can be parsed by `strtotime`. I don't have a way to test yours but I used a format like "Jan 1, 2009", so that ought to work.

Comment: Try using the `/me/feed` connection instead of `/me/statuses`

Comment: I've just tried both and neither works... Did you test them yourself in the Graph API Explorer tools? http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: yeah, they work on my account. are you granting the `read_stream` permission?

Comment: yes I am. My API call was (id)/feed/Jan 1, 2009 and (id)/statuses/Jan 1, 2009. None of them work... Well Facebook filed this as a bug as well, so it must be not working for them either.

Comment: You aren't using `id/feed/jan 1, 2009`, are you? That's not going to work. Paste `me/feed?until=jan 1, 2009` into the API explorer (make sure there is a valid access token there).

Comment: Yes! That works actually! So it does work with feed but not statuses in fact. It is still a bug in their part but thanks for this :)

Comment: it still doesn't work if there's a really big gap between posts. like if I have a post at (timestamp) 1208635271 and then 1295911649, then &until=1295911649 doesn't show anything, empty data. it only shows when I change it to &until=1265911649, so I have to manualy move the timestamp to older dates to check for older posts

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice that. Did you file a new bug for that? If so can I get a link to that? I don't even know when Facebook is going to work on my original bug.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has since [confirmed this as a bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/104392053016265).  If you have followed Facebook's bug tracker ever, unfortunately that means there is very little if any chance they will actually fix this.

Comment: Yes I've submitted a few bugs before, but was hoping that they will fix this one :(

Comment: Each week they accept/confirm way more bugs than they fix each week and the bugs they do actually fix are the ones their dev partners (like zyngas, spotify, etc) run into.

Comment: OffBySome, that's probably very true.  Hence why it could be worth a company's while to become a partner.  Money makes the world go 'round as they say.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to paginate.  Limit is limited.  Please read http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Comment: Tried to paginate it. My GET request: (my_user_id)/statuses?limit=20&offset=90. Still doesn't give me anything earlier than 2011.

Comment: Strange, similar for me too.  I can't get anything older than 2010-12-17T15:23:37+0000.  You should log it as a bug with Facebook.

Comment: Previously I can't get anything older than 2009 too. I was hoping Facebook monitors stackoverflow, as it is listed as one of the technical help resource on http://developers.facebook.com/support/.

Comment: Not really, you need to file an official bug report at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Alright I filed the bug, would help if people vote on the bug I guess :)